# Proving that $\left|\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}\right| \le \frac{2}{|z|^2}$?

Tags: inequality, contour-integration

I am wondering if I'm missing some sort of triangle inequality trick to show this, or if I need more context. Can this be solved purely algebraically?

Thanks.

Edit: I've tried this, but I'm not sure I'm using the triangle inequality properly.

$\left|\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}\right| \le \frac{1}{|z|^2} + \left|\frac{-e^{iz}}{z^2}\right| = \frac{1}{|z|^2} + \frac{|-e^{iz}|}{|z^2|} = \frac{1}{|z|^2} + \frac{1}{|z^2|} = \frac{2}{|z|^2}$

Comment: There must be some restriction on $z$. The inequality does not hold for all non-zero complex $z$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks. As far as I know, there are no explicit restrictions on $z$. How do you know that there must be a restriction?

Comment: It would imply that $z \mapsto 1 - e^{iz}$ is a bounded entire function, and hence by Liouville's theorem a constant, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Gary I see. I have yet to go over that, but we will soon. I've written something (which I'm assuming is wrong, considering $z$ needs a restriction). Could you tell me where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What you did is correct as long as $z$ is real. Otherwise $|e^{-iz}| \neq 1$.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense but why is $|e^{iz}| \ne 1$? Isn't $|e^{iz}| = |-(cosz + isinz)| = \sqrt{(-cos^2(z)) + (-sin^2(z))} = 1?$

Comment: Ah, I think I see. The reason is demonstrated in Bernard's answer.

Comment: The second equality is not true if $\cos$ and $\sin$ are not real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual triangle inequality is enough, as the domain of this inequality is $|z|\ne 0$, it amounts to proving 
$$\bigl|1-\mathrm e^{iz}\bigr|\le 2. $$
Now, say $z=x+iy$, we have
$$\bigl|1-\mathrm e^{iz}\bigr|\le 1+ \bigl|\mathrm e^{iz}\bigr|=1+\bigl|\mathrm e^{ix}\bigr|\bigl|\mathrm e^{-y}\bigr|=1+\bigl|\mathrm e^{-y}\bigr|,$$
so it is true if $y\ge 0$.

If $y<0$,  it is easy to see that for each value of the argument, there exists a value of $z$ for which the inequality is false.

Comment: @WilliamPhoenix: Thank you for correcting f my typos! I really should reread before posting…